# Oracle SQL parameterized query via Unix Shell

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, parameter-passing, sqlplus

I have a Shell batch and I want to execute a sql query by using Oracle SQL plus prompt in Unix environment.

The query has a parameter that must change dynamically width batch execution parameters (a Date).

Here is the query in MY_QUERY.sql file:

`SELECT ID || ';' || NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE BIRTH=&1`

And the Unix Shell script is:

```
LOGIN=$1
PASSWORD=$2
OUTPUT_FOLDER=$3
DATE=$4
echo "Date_birth: '${DATE}'"
echo exit | sqlplus ${LOGIN}/${PASSWORD} @"../sql/MY_QUERY.sql" "'${DATE}'" >> "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/Output.csv"
```

I find that the Output.csv file is empty. But when I put the date in the query directly , I have the output like wanted.

```
SELECT ID || ';' || NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE BIRTH='31/12/2014'
```

PS: The date is not empty or null, because it's displayed using the line above

```
echo "Date_birth: '${DATE}'"
```

PS: The wanted result is diplayed also when I execute this line directly using SqlPlus prompt `@c:\sql\MY_QUERY.sql '31/12/2014'`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that your $DATE doesn't contain white characters.
Suppose, that your question concerns UNIX solely (because in your example was not UNIX).

Then change your sql script to

```
SELECT ID || ';' || NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE BIRTH='31/12/2014';
exit;
```

and change the last line of your UNIX script to

```
sqlplus $LOGIN/$PASSWORD @/absolute_path/MY_QUERY.sql $DATE
```

i.e. without pipe.  (If that works, you can return to your relative path and redirection.)
If the issue persists, add after $PASSWORD@$ORACLE_SID   or  @TWO_TASK, that contains database name und must be exported.
If it doesn't solve the issue, let me see a content of your output.

Comment: I have finded the problem. The single quote of date doesn't finded when replacing the parameter &1 in the query. Here is the sqlplus output:
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecté à :
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

old  6 : AND p.birth= TO_DATE(&1,'dd/mm/YYYY')
new   6 : AND p.birth= TO_DATE(31/12/2014,'dd/mm/YYYY')
AND p.birth= TO_DATE(31/12/2014,'dd/mm/YYYY')
                         *
ERREUR à la ligne 6 :
ORA-01858: Caractère non numérique trouvé à la place d'un caractère numérique

Comment: I have founded the solution to my problem. I have added the single quote to parameter directly in the query like that: SELECT ID || ';' || NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE BIRTH='&1';

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. I have added the single quote to parameter directly in the query like that:

```
SELECT ID || ';' || NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE BIRTH='&1';
```